# C# DX What is this param mean?

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx

I ran into this while using slimDX

```
MessagePump.Run(form, () => { });
```

What does () => { } do?

Comment: `()=>{}` is an empty action. **Empty Lambda Expression**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `() => {}` is an empty lambda expression. The function `MessagePump.Run` is [defined as](http://slimdx.org/docs/#M_SlimDX_Windows_MessagePump_Run_2):

```
public static void Run(
Form form,
MainLoop mainLoop
)
```

`MainLoop` is [defined as](http://slimdx.org/docs/#T_SlimDX_Windows_MainLoop):

```
public delegate void MainLoop()
```

So it is delegate which does not expects any parameters. So when you pass `() => {}` it is as good as a method that do nothing like:

```
public void MainLoopImpl()
{
    //empty method
}
```

Now create `MainLoop` instance:

```
var mLoop = new MainLoop(MainLoopImpl);
//or alternative syntax
MainLoop mLoop = MainLoopImpl;

//CALL Run

MessagePump.Run(form, mLoop);
```

Details about declaring, creating and using delegates (including `lambda expression` declaration way) is explained in detail on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176.aspx).